# How to parse Json data with many variables?

Tags: json, vb.net

How can I parse Json code with differents variable but with the same id.
I'll explain, Im new using Json, so I want to parse :

```
{"title": {
   "runs": [
     {
   "text": "Peter Tosh - Legalize It"
     }
   ],
   "accessibility": {
     "accessibilityData": {
   "label": "Peter Tosh - Legalize It by Bondade Ã© Nosso HÃ¡bito 8 years ago 4 minutes, 46 seconds"
     }
   }
 },
 "index": {
   "simpleText": "1"
 },
 "shortBylineText": {
   "runs": [
     {
   "text": "Bondade Ã© Nosso HÃ¡bito",
   "navigationEndpoint": {
     "clickTrackingParams": "CD0QxjQYACITCMn2heSTz-wCFUmw1Qod1hMDdw==",
     "commandMetadata": {
       "webCommandMetadata": {
         "url": "/user/Bruno12170",
         "webPageType": "WEB_PAGE_TYPE_CHANNEL",
         "rootVe": 3611
       }
     },
     "browseEndpoint": {
       "browseId": "UCY1IJY2IYNVfD7R-JbgQGbQ",
       "canonicalBaseUrl": "/user/Bruno12170"
     }
   }
     }
   ]
 },
 "lengthText": {
   "accessibility": {
     "accessibilityData": {
   "label": "4 minutes, 46 seconds"
     }
   },
   "simpleText": "4:46"
 },
 "navigationEndpoint": {
   "clickTrackingParams": "CD0QxjQYACITCMn2heSTz-wCFUmw1Qod1hMDdzIKcGxwcF92aWRlb1okVkxQTDRfRHg4OGRwdTdlcGZINnlid3FKcGY5dUwydEFsMzY4mgEDEPos",
   "commandMetadata": {
     "webCommandMetadata": {
   "url": "/watch?v=j6QkVTx2d88&list=PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368&index=1",
   "webPageType": "WEB_PAGE_TYPE_WATCH",
   "rootVe": 3832
     }}}
```

What I want to parse from this is:

> "text": "Peter Tosh - Legalize It"

> "url": "/watch?v=j6QkVTx2d88&list=PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368&index=1

How can I parse them in a page where there are many elements(songs)?
How can I use For each to do so? Thanks

edit1:

```
  Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

        Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
        Dim incstr As IO.Stream = Nothing


        incstr = wc.OpenRead("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368")

        Using rd As New IO.StreamReader(incstr)
            RichTextBox1.Text = rd.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        Dim o As String = ("{""title"":  {
   ""runs"": [
     {
   ""text"": ""Peter Tosh - Legalize It""
     }
   ],
   ""accessibility"": {
     ""accessibilityData"": {
   ""label"": ""Peter Tosh - Legalize It by Bondade Ã© Nosso HÃ¡bito 8 years ago 4 minutes, 46 seconds""
     }
   }
 },
 ""index"": {
   ""simpleText"": ""1""
 },
 ""shortBylineText"": {
   ""runs"": [
     {
   ""text"": ""Bondade Ã© Nosso HÃ¡bito"",
   ""navigationEndpoint"": {
     ""clickTrackingParams"": ""CD0QxjQYACITCMn2heSTz-wCFUmw1Qod1hMDdw=="",
     ""commandMetadata"": {
       ""webCommandMetadata"": {
         ""url"": ""/user/Bruno12170"",
         ""webPageType"": ""WEB_PAGE_TYPE_CHANNEL"",
         ""rootVe"": 3611
       }
     },
     ""browseEndpoint"": {
       ""browseId"": ""UCY1IJY2IYNVfD7R-JbgQGbQ"",
       ""canonicalBaseUrl"": ""/user/Bruno12170""
     }
   }
     }
   ]
 },
 ""lengthText"": {
   ""accessibility"": {
     ""accessibilityData"": {
   ""label"": ""4 minutes, 46 seconds""
     }
   },
   ""simpleText"": ""4:46""
 },
 ""navigationEndpoint"": {
   ""clickTrackingParams"": ""CD0QxjQYACITCMn2heSTz-wCFUmw1Qod1hMDdzIKcGxwcF92aWRlb1okVkxQTDRfRHg4OGRwdTdlcGZINnlid3FKcGY5dUwydEFsMzY4mgEDEPos"",
   ""commandMetadata"": {
     ""webCommandMetadata"": {
   ""url"": ""/watch?v=j6QkVTx2d88&list=PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368&index=1"",
   ""webPageType"": ""WEB_PAGE_TYPE_WATCH"",
   ""rootVe"": 3832
     } } }")
        Dim webLink = JObject.Parse(o)("navigationEndpoint")("commandMetadata")("webCommandMetadata")("url")
        MsgBox(webLink)
    End Sub
```

Unfortunately it is not working.. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: With a class model and Json.Net or System.Text.Json. That JSON is missing the enclosing `{` and two more at the end (for a total of three: `}}}`), so you probably have a partial JSON there.

Comment: Yes it's just a partial Json, the page is quite big with a lot of songs like that. I'll try to see some documentation about what you suggested me.

Comment: Well, if you actually have the full JSON then there's no problem. You can find some on-line resouces that provide the conversion from JSON to .Net classes. After you have the model (class structure), deserializing the JSON is a single command.

Comment: I hope so, I'm downloading the source code of a youtube playlist, so I guess the Json is completed... I'm reading some documentation about  System.Text.Json, but lots of those are for single elements. But in case of many variable, in my case are songs, how can I make a loop to find all of them existing?

Comment: System.Text.Json is related to .Net Core. If you use .Net Framework, install Json.Net (`Newtonsoft.Json`, using Visual Studio's `NuGet Package Manager`). You don't have to loop anything, you just have to build a class model that describes the JSON. Looking at the JSON structure here, the internal `Paste JSON as Classes` function of Visual Studio should get it right, probably. Since the JSON contain more object that start with `Title` that describe a song, you'll have a `List<Song>` after deserialization.

Comment: I don't know If I am doing correctly, but it seems that there is no point to paste JSON as classes if I just need two object, sorry If I am wrong, but I am trying to make it simple..
I'm editing uploading the code I wrote so far, would be nice if you'll give your opinion. Thanks

Comment: I uploaded the code i tried. .

Comment: `dim webLink = JObject.Parse(json)("navigationEndpoint")("commandMetadata")("webCommandMetadata")("url")`. The title.runs.text is `dim titleText = JObject.Parse(json)("title")("runs")(0)("text")`. If you build the model, you do that once then you have all of those object/properties already accessible as .Net classes/properties.

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks a lot for your kind help. Unfortunately, I think I am doing some mistakes because I get error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'navigationEndpoint', line 52, position 10.'. I am goint to update the code I am using

Comment: What I posted here is related to the JSON object, not your code. The two variables, `webLink` and `titleText` are generated from the source JSON text. It's all that's needed. If you have more objects (an object start with `{"title":  { ... }`), then access one by one in a loop and use the two line of code I've posted in the loop. -- The Encoding is not correct, you should have used UTF-8 Encoding. -- I see you have used WebClient: this class doesn't care about the source Encoding, you have to set it yourself with `[WebClient].Encoding = Encoding.UTF8` (before downloading, of course)

Comment: Oh I see, so I can use your  two line of code, but I don't understand still how to use them. I mean, Which of the 3 past codes Should I use? I added the encoding before download, 
so now what is blocking me from use  Dim webLink = JObject.Parse(RichTextBox1.Text)("navigationEndpoint")("commandMetadata")("webCommandMetadata")("url") as a single line code?
I'm already downloading the html source in richtextbox.. Shouldn't this parse rtb1 and extract what I need?

Comment: Your RichTextBox contains the whole HTML source. You have to extract the JSON parts from there. You should check whether YouTube has an API you can query that already returns you that JSON alone...

Comment: [YouTube PlayListItems API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list). In the `Try this API` test panel, specify `contentDetails,snippet` as the `part` content and `PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368` as the `playlistId` content. Querying this API will return a JSON with all the Items in the PlayList, plus the Video Id, the Images in different formats etc. You should check this out (scraping the HTML when an API is available is not really a good choice, the HTML can change at any time).

Comment: Tha't s exactly what I was doing, I was about to come here to show you that 
[link](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+id&playlistId=PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368&key=AIzaSyAJLLCFuQLEE6LFjwwPCxvo9T6DC3nLNPs) is the completed query, but it's quite weird.. It doesn't contain all of the songs in it.

Comment: Set `maxResults = 100` (you'll get 12 back of course :)

Comment: Yes Jimi, Tha't s correct, but If you look in the bottom ""pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 277,
"resultsPerPage": 50" so it is not possible to show all the together, Am I right? Also, where Am I supposed to find the second page? 
All this stuff was bringing me on the road of scraping html.. Cause I know sometimes api got limitations..  Thanks

Comment: If you have more that 50 elements in the PlayList, then you get back a `nextPageToken` entry in the main class object. You can use this token to query the next page, setting the `pageToken=[The Provided Token String]` query tuple.