# How to scrape youtube data

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

i want to get video title,Description,but item is nul,i think HtmlAgilityPack can't read youtube'custom tag for example "ytd-page-manager"

```
 string url = "https://www.youtube.com/c/charlieputh/featured";
    HtmlWeb webClient = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = webClient.Load(url);
    HtmlNodeCollection item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse[2]/ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer/div[1]/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer[3]/div[3]/ytd-shelf-renderer/div[1]/div[2]/yt-horizontal-list-renderer/div[2]/div/ytd-grid-video-renderer[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a");
    string note = item[0].InnerHtml;
    Console.WriteLine(note);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: simply check every element individually starting from the root element.

Comment: It is better to have the searching be done in steps so you can see where it goes wrong.  Also you can read it easier.

Comment: Use YouTube API ? See [How to use the YouTube API to extract video titles and next page token?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547256/14171304).

Answer (score 0):

If you download the web page:

```
const string url = "https://www.youtube.com/c/charlieputh/featured";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, @"C:\...\featured.html");
}
```

You get a file in which 'ytd-page-manager' doesn't appear. When you make scraping, take in mind that pages can load content dynamically and a simple request of a url isn't enought.

You need do scraping with a browser, like CefSharp. You need a previous work and study (there are samples in CefSharp pages) but after that, you can cover any scenary. If you can do with a simple request, do it (simple and efficient) and, when you need more complex scenaries (logins, redirections, waits...), you'll use the browser.