# WinForms Listview renders with dark scrollbars, how they did it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, listview

I just discovered what seems to be a bug on VS2022 but none the less it also raised a cool question on how to reproduce.
The legacy form for choosing "Toolbox items" aka Controls does render with a dark-style scrollbar on the listview, and I was wondering if someone even knows how to reproduce this on a standard WinForms listview.

[image: NET Components showing dark-style scrollbars on listview]

Comment: That's a WPF ListView. The dark tone of the Scrollbars is determined by the Theme currently applied. You probably have Dark Theme enabled in VS. The ListViewItems (and the dialog in general) use different templates / styles

Comment: Oh, thats WPF? you sure? I was under the impression it was MFC/WinForms or however their are called, that would explain it.... thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The interface of VS is a composite structure. You have a mix of Win32 / WinForms, WPF, XAML elements -- You can customize the Theme of WinForms controls (e.g., see the animation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547256/7444103), those are custom / themed Scrollbars applied to a FlowLayoutPanel and a ListBox). Take a look at the available [uxtheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/) functions. Scrollbars are *special*, though. You have to *dig deeper* to customize them (or replace them entirely)

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score -1):

As Jimi said, this interface is based on WPF. Starting from Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio's UI is mainly based on WPF.

You can refer to Jimi's advice to make the UI style of Winforms tend to be WPF.

In addition, you can also use WPF controls directly in Winforms.

Because this interface uses the ListBox in WPF, you can make the user control of the ListBox in WPF and add it to Winforms.

1. First, please create a Winforms (.net framework) project.
2. Add a new item User Control (WPF) to the Winforms (.net framework) project

[image]

3. Build the project after adding ListBox to User Control (WPF)
4. Add User Control (WPF) in the toolbar to the form

[image]