Downloading video from Youtube using WebClient
I am trying to download Youtube Video from embed url using WebClient (videos only channel owner allowed me).
Here is an example from StackOverflow's youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g)
But the problems starts here. I use the code below to download some img or mp4 files normally in C#.
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(
        new System.Uri("https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g"),
        "C:\\YoutubeTest\\yttestvideo.mp4"
    );
}

It actually downloads some file (probably broken cuz file is 87 KB.) however it gives me error when I run it.

Windows Media Player cannot play. The player may not support the file content or the codec used to compress its files.

So is it possible to download a video from this link using WebClient or is there any option to download it from C# side?
Note: I am not seeking a library etc.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547256/14171304

Downloading videos is feature of YouTube premium, so I guess there's not easy way to get it done. As far as i remember when i anylzed the topic, YouTube sends video in chunks from domain different than youtube. You need to get the chunks, analyze how to join them and maybe after taht you'd have a video.

Deleting and Reasking the question does not change to much (beside that i/we consider that as rude). You have downloaded a website and gave it the mp4 extension. That does not change the fact that its the website and not the content of video played in the videoplayer on that website. Just open the file in an editor and see for yourself. You don't have to guess by the file size. if you want the video you need to capture the stream (that is encrypted) and encode into a video container format you want to have (mp4 for example)

@MichałTurczyn YT Premium gives you a personalized format that is meant to be played only by the youtube player that needs your personal authentication for playing the file and is typically also time restricted. That its called "download" is a marketing trick to suggest its somehow something standard that can be taken shared and played everywhere while it isn't.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJtJXMKpl2g serves HTML... you're downloading the HTML, not a video file. In future you can simply open the file with a hex editor to get some understanding of the content.
